# Contacts provider not appears in "google contacts application"

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I wrote a Contacts provider. It is quite configurable via "Settings/Accounts", it correctly sync contacts from remote server and these contacts are visible in the "Google contacts" application.

But in the setting "Contacts to display" of the "Google Contacts application" I can't see my provider (but I see others, like skype).

Platform: Android >= 5.0

Any idea?
TIA
Roberto C.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've created an xml file for you SyncProvider, that xml file has a field `userVisible`, make sure it's `true`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:contentAuthority="com.example.my_sync_provider"
        android:accountType="com.example.my_type"
        android:userVisible="true"
        android:supportsUploading="true"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true" />
```

read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
and also this is a must read: http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/ (part 2 as well)

Comment: thanks. I have this attribute. I discovered that the problem was generated by a doubled calendar-related xml which refer an undefined account type

Comment: cool, you can add your own answer to this question on stackoverflow, and mark it as the accepted answer, as it might help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

thanks. I have this attribute. I discovered that the problem was generated by a doubled calendar-related xml which refer an undefined account type