# Sync contacts android with remote database

Tags: android, postgresql, web-services, synchronization, contacts

I try to synchronize the contacts of the mobile device with a database in this case Postgresql, the way I do it does not seem to be the most convenient.

```
    public void sincronizarcontactos(){

// Se tiene permiso
final String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER};
String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        projeccion,
        selectionClause,
        null,
        sortOrder);

HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();
int indexOfNormalizedNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER);
progreso= ProgressDialog.show(SincronizarActivity.this, "", "Sincronizando...", true);

int o=0;

while(c.moveToNext()){
    o++;
    progreso.show();
    String email=c.getString(0).replace(" ","_");
    String normalizedNumber = c.getString(indexOfNormalizedNumber);
    if(normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)){
        String urlinsert="http://192.168.1.33/Agenda/insert_persona.php?name="+c.getString(0)+
                "&city=Paute&email="+email+"@gmail.com&phone="+c.getString(1)+"&mobile="+c.getString(2);

        JsonObjectRequest solicitud = new JsonObjectRequest(urlinsert,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject datos) {
                Toast.makeText(SincronizarActivity.this, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progreso.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SincronizarActivity.this, "Tuvimos un problema de conexión...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        VolleyRP.addToQueue(solicitud,request,this,volley);
    }

    if (o==projeccion.length){
        progreso.dismiss();
    }

}
progreso.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(SincronizarActivity.this, "Se han sicronizado sus contactos...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
c.close(); }
```

As I say it does not seem to me to be the most correct way, I would like you to help me to get them to synchronize automatically, example as in the photo ...

[Imagen de referencia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzjIM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The query code looks ok, I think the question you're asking is "how do I run a contact sync operation integrated into Android's ecosystem".

The answer would by to create a Contacts SyncAdapter, see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44566012/819355